# Style Trigger on sub-property of a DependencyProperty

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I have a control I want to style depending on the set `MessageType` of a custom `Message` type `DependencyProperty` of that control.

**Custom Type:**

```
public class Message : ObservableObject
{
    public MessageTypes MessageType
    {
        get { return _messageType; }
        set {
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => MessageType);
            _messageType = value;
        } 
    }

    public string Text { ... }

    ...
}
```

**Control:**

```
public class MessageControl : Control
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MessageProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "Message",
            typeof(Message),
            typeof(MessageControl),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null,
                FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));

    public Message Message
    {
        get
        {
            return (Message)GetValue(MessageProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(MessageProperty, value);
        }
    }
}
```

**Style:**

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="MessageControlTemplate"
                 TargetType="controls:MessageControl">
    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Message.Text,
                             RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
    </Border>
</ControlTemplate>

<Style TargetType="controls:MessageControl">
    <Setter Property="Template"
            Value="{StaticResource MessageControlTemplate}" />

    <Style.Triggers>
        <!-- HERE IS THE ISSUE -->
        <Trigger Property="Message.MessageType"
                 Value="{x:Static classes:MessageType.Error}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

So the problem is that I can't add a Trigger for `Message.MessageType` (or basically any other sub property).

Is it even possible to accomplish this? Or should I just create two properties in `MessageControl` for `Text` and `MessageType`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it with a DataTrigger:

```
<Style TargetType="controls:MessageControl">
    ...
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Message.MessageType,
                               RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
                     Value="{x:Static classes:MessageType.Error}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

You should also raise the PropertyChanged event after setting the property's backing field:

```
public MessageType MessageType
{
    get { return _messageType; }
    set
    {
        _messageType = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(() => MessageType);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks totally works! About the PropertyChanged thing, I was just coding this out of my mind because the real code is somewhat more complex, but usually you are right about the order.